# Counting tuples which satisfy certain additive conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I have $4$-tuples

$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $ a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 = n$ and $2 | a_2$ and $3 | a_3$ and $4 | a_4$

For example, if $n = 2,$ then we could have $(2,0,0,0)$ or $(0,2,0,0)$. If $n = 3,$ then we have $(0,0,3,0)$ and $(3,0,0,0)$ and $(1,2,0,0)$.

How can I count how many tuples I have for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$? It looks like it really blows up after $n = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer (valid for $n \geq 3$) is the closest integer to
$$
\frac{1}{288}(2n^3 + 30n^2 + 135n + 175) + \frac{(-1)^n n}{32}.
$$
This seems to agree with Giulio's answer.

The answer will be the coefficient of degree $n$ in the product series of
$$
(1 + x + x^2 + \dots)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots)(1 + x^3 + x^6 + \dots)(1 + x^4 + x^8 + \dots) = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}.
$$

According to Wolfram Alpha, the partial fractions decomposition of this rational function is
$$
\frac{x + 1}{9(x^2 + x + 1)} + \frac{1}{8 (x^2 + 1)} - \frac{68 x^3 - 263 x^2 + 358 x - 175}{288 (x - 1)^4} + \frac{4 x + 5}{32 (x + 1)^2}.
$$
The general terms of the series corresponding to the last three terms can be determined using the binomial series. Letting $\omega$ be a complex cube root of unity, the first term can be rewritten as $-\frac{1}{18}\frac{\omega}{x - \omega} -\frac{1}{18}\frac{\omega^2}{x - \omega^2}$, and then the same method can be applied to that term. Presumably, there will be distinct formulae according to $n \mod 6$.

Using complex numbers, the answer won't depend formally on $n \mod 6$. We get
$$
\frac{1}{18}(\omega^n + \omega^{-n})
+ \frac{1}{16}(i^n + i^{-n}) -\frac{68}{288}(-1)^{n-3}\binom{-4}{n-3} + \frac{263}{288}(-1)^{n-2}\binom{-4}{n-2} - \frac{358}{288}(-1)^{n-1}\binom{-4}{n-1} + \frac{175}{288}(-1)^n\binom{-4}{n} + \frac{4}{32}\binom{-2}{n-1} + \frac{5}{32}\binom{-2}{n},
$$
where $\omega^n + \omega^{-n}$ is $2$ or $-1$ according as whether $n$ divides $3$ or not, $i^n + i^{-n}$ is $2(-1)^{n/2}$ or $0$ according as whether $n$ is even or odd, and
$$
\binom{-2}{n} = (-1)^n(n+1), \quad \binom{-4}{n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{6}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1),$$
except when $n < 0$, in which case $\binom{-2}{n}$ and $\binom{-4}{n}$ are zero. The first two terms being much smaller than $1$ in absolute value, we can say in short that the answer for $n \geq 3$ is the closest integer to
$$\frac{1}{288}(2n^3 + 30n^2 + 135n + 175) + \frac{(-1)^n}{32}(n+5).$$

Since $1/9 + 1/8 + 5/32 < 1/2$, we can also ignore the last constant term.

A way to just get the answer from Wolfram Alpha or some similar system would be to take the $n$th derivative of $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$ evaluated at $x = 0$ and divide the answer by $n!$. The free online version of Wolfram Alpha is telling me its computation time is too long for this request, so I can't actually do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to count how many ways there are to write
$$
n=k_1+2k_2+3k_3+4k_4
$$
with nonnegative integers $k_1,...,k_4$.

This is the same as the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$
(1+x+x^2+..)(1+x^2+x^4+..)
(1+x^3+x^6+..)
(1+x^4+x^8+..)=
\frac 1{1-x}
\frac 1{1-x^2}
\frac 1{1-x^3}
\frac 1{1-x^4}
$$
$$
=1 + x + 2 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 5 x^4 + 6 x^5 + 9 x^6 + 11 x^7 + 15 x^{8} + 
 18 x^9 + 23 x^{10} + 27 x^{11} + 34 x^{12} + 39 x^{13} + 47 x^{14} + 54 x^{15} + 
 64 x^{16} + 72 x^{17} + 84 x^{18} + 94 x^{19} + 108 x^{20} +\mathcal O(x^{21}).
$$
It is the number of partitions of $n$ with parts at most equal to $4$.